# Comments Application SEO

Tags: php, seo

I am developing a commenting application. Users will be able to integrate this application in Blogs. I am unsure how to make the comments searchable in Search Engines.

What I want is all the comments which are being posted should be included in Search Engine results when searched with relevant keywords.

Please give me some hint how to do this. Do I need to use meta tags ? If so, how should I create them?

Comment: Are you looking to build something similar to Disqus?

Comment: This question was 12 years ahead of it's time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure exactly which users would want to implement your commenting system into their blog considering a lot of people will just use wordpress, or another popular blogging platform - or if they have developed their own, I would have thought them 'savvy' enough to also implement their own system.

Anyway, onto your question:

You cannot force comments entered through your system to receive any 'special attention' from search engines. It's very much down to the content users create as actual comments. If users post comments like "Nice post" or "Good work", they probably aren't (and shouldn't) be included in SERPs (search engine results pages). If somebody posts something insightful, it might be included - but if we're assuming it will follow standard blog commenting practise - i.e. they're situated *below* the blog post, the content within them will not have as much of an 'effect' on what results the entire page appears for.

On the other hand, if you had an extremely popular/valuable blog post, comments would more likely be crawled and indexed along with the entire page.

Basically - You can't force comments to rank, it's purely down to the value of the page they're situated on and the value of the comment itself. When I refer to value, I mean whether SE's think it's valuable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why people would want to use this system either but maybe there will be features above and beyond normal blog commenting?

Either way have you thought about using some of the micro format tags in the schema.org specification? Search engines are using these to find richer sources of content for the SERPS and there are specific ones for blog comments.

Take a look at http://schema.org/docs/full.html for details of the different tags you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You could build something into your system that spiders the post the comment system is placed on and assigns it a category (this would be easy if installed on say WordPress, but hard on custom pages).

Once you have the category you could have a site set up that just shows off comments people have posted put into these categories.

This would mean that so long as Google is spidering your site regularly (by using best practice methods this shouldn't be an issue) it wouldn't matter a great deal if the site that the comment was posted on was getting spidered and listed regularly.

This might leave you with duplicate content issues, but it would be doubtful because the comment will only be a small snippet of a page that is constantly changing when on the blog and on your site that shows all comments it will have more prominence.